# non literal reference to self

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a planet 'class' in javascript. When the user clicks on a html5 canvas the appropriate planet's manageClick function is called which should change the contents of a certain div. The content should change to a button. If the user clicks it then the planet's function createShip should be called.

Now the issue is how do I pass in a reference to the planet itself ? I tried to make a new function that calls createShip() on any object and then call it with the argument 'this'. But it doesn't seem to work. What would be the proper way to do this ?

```
Planet.prototype.createShip =function() {...}

Planet.prototype.manageClick=function() {
    $(".dropdown").html("<button onclick=\"buyship(this)\">Buy a ship</button>");
}

function buyship(obj) {
    obj.createShip();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.buyship()`?

Comment: Watch your capitalization. `...prototype.CreateShip` doesn't match `obj.createShip()`. Also, use camel case (`createShip`) when naming methods or functions that are to be called directly. Use pascal case (`CreateShip`, `ManageClick`) on functions that are to be called as constructor functions (i.e. var obj = new CreateShip()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use onclick. Instead use jquery to create the button and bind a function to the click event. Using the `.bind` method of a function you can bind the `this` value to the function explicitly rather than passing it as a parameter.

```
Planet.prototype.createShip =function() {...}

Planet.prototype.ManageClick=function() {
    var self = this;
    var buyShip = $("<button id='buyShip'>Buy a ship</button>").click(buyship.bind(self))
    $(".dropdown").append(buyShip);
}

function buyship() {
    this.createShip();
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/brko5jr7/1/

Comment: Use `'<button id="buyShip">Buy a ship</button>'` or `"<button id='buyShip'>Buy a ship</button>"`

Answer (score 0):

I hate using `this` because if you connect any of your object's methods to things like jQuery event handlers, `this` can become a real pain in the rear if you don't code things just right.

I don't use the `prototype` approach for coding classes as you did, but prefer to write them as a function declaration.

```
var Planet = function(){
    var ref = this;
    ref.CreateShip = function () {
        ref.xyz = 123456;
    };

    ref.ManageClick = function(){
        ref.someproperty = "something";
    }
}
```

You'll notice that right off the bat, I declare  variable `ref` which points to the object in scope, and I then use `ref` inside of members instead of `this`.  It makes for better readability, in my opinion.  YMMV.

Instantiation is still the same:

var instance = new Planet();

Comment: There is an issue with not using `prototypes`, however. Declaring methods in the constructor means a new method (memory value) will be made for the constructed object, while methods on the `prototype` remain static (i.e. shared between instances). If constructing a lot of things or having a ton of constructor methods, this can cause pretty bleak memory / performance issues.

Comment: I'd STILL create that `ref` member in the constructor, in any case, to make the object reference less ambiguous.